# .innerHTML is blocked from other function?

Tags: javascript

I want a other text on a button until a validation progress.
But the .innerHTML does not change the HTML.

```js
var keeybtn = document.getElementById('kyloginbtn');
    
function checkForm() {
 keeybtn.innerHTML = 'Go';
    var email = document.getElementById("kymail").value;
    if (email === '') {
        keeybtn.innerHTML='Fill Email field';
  message();
  
  return false;
    }
    else {
        document.getElementById("kyloginform").submit();
        validate(email);
    }
}
```

When I comment out the "validate(email)" function it works.

```js
function validate(email) {
 var xmlhttp;
  
 if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
   {// for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
   xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
   }
 else
   {// for IE6, IE5
   xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
   } 
   
     xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function()
     {
         if (xmlhttp.readyState != 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
             keeybtn.innerHTML = "Validating..";
         }
         else if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
             keeybtn.innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
             if(xmlhttp.responseText == "ok") {
              reloadPage();
             }
             else {
              message();
             }
         }
         else {
             console.log("Error");
         }
     }
     xmlhttp.open("GET", "pk-login.php?email=" + email, false);
    
 xmlhttp.send();
}
```

If everything is valid xmlhttp.Text appear on the button.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "blocked" or "not working".

Comment: If its a button <input type="button"... .value ='new value';

Answer (score 0):

You may achieve this by the following the example shown as below:

```
<form id="kyloginform" action="#" method="post">
    <input type="text" id="kymail" value="" />
    <button type="submit" id="kyloginbtn" onclick="return checkForm()">Submit</button>
</form>

function checkForm() {
    var button = document.getElementById('kyloginbtn');
    button.innerHTML = 'Submitting';
    var email = document.getElementById("kymail").value;
    if (email === '') {
        button.innerHTML = 'Please fill in email field';
        message();

        // Prevent form submit when validation error.
        return false;
    }
    else {
        document.getElementById("kyloginform").submit();
        validate(email);
    }
}
```

For working example, please refer to this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/zeskysee/n7tevL7y/16/

Hope this help :)

Comment: After checking your fiddle, it seems like when your email is empty, you will call the method "message()". `function message() {
    setTimeout(function(){
   keeybtn.innerHTML='Login with Keey';
 },3000);
};` This method will update your keeybtn innerhtml back to 'Login with Keey'. Is this the expected behavior?

Comment: Yes, this the expected behavior. The method "message()" has a timeout that the user can see the error message a few second and then again see "Login with Keey".

Comment: Please check the following updated fiddle to see is this what you want http://jsfiddle.net/zeskysee/hy2v6tLj/1/. _Note: Updated `var button = document.getElementById('kyloginbtn');` to local variable due to fiddle no wrap does not support global variable. You may use global variable in your code._

Comment: Thanks but your last link does not work :/ Ok it works without ] i will check

Comment: I updated my previous comment, please check. _Not use to comment formatting - -"_

Answer (score 0):

Found a Solution, the ajax call must set to async

```js
xmlhttp.open("GET", "pk-login.php?email=" + email, true);
```